# Stuck at trying to plot a dispersion relation EM wave

Tags: plotting

We are considering the matrix transformation of an electromagnetic wave through periodic media. 
The constant is given as:

```
mu1= 1; mu2 = 1; e1 = 2.25;  e2 = 1;  d1 = 1*10^-7;  d2 = 1*10^-7;  Z1 = (mu1/e1)^1/2;  Z2 = (mu2/e2)^1/2;    q = Z2/Z1;  k1 = (mu1*e1) w;  k2 = (mu2*e2) w;
```

and the transfer matrix, where T12 transformation from medium 1 to medium 2 through the surface, similar to T21; and T1d is transfer in the media 1 of width d, similar for medium 2:

```
T12 = 1/2*{{1 + q, 1 - q}, {1 - q, 1 + q}};
T21 = 1/2*{{1 + 1/q, 1 - 1/q}, {1 - 1/q, 1 + 1/q}};
T1d = {{Exp[I*k1*d1], 0}, {0, Exp[-I*k1*d1]}};
T2d = {{Exp[I*k2*d2], 0}, {0, Exp[-I*k2*d2]}};


T = T12.T2d.T21.T1d;
```

The Bloch wavenumber is

```
Kb = Simplify[1/(d1 + d2)*ArcCos[Re[Tr[T]]/2]];
```

where Kb is function of omega. Here is a dispersion relation.
Notice that Tr(T)<2 Kb is real, and Tr(T)>2 Kb is imaginary.

How do I make a dispersion relation plot using `RegionPlot`? 
Something like this:
[image: plot]
or this
[image: plot]
Thank you

Comment: Can you explain a bit about what's "dispersion relation plot"? Also, there're 2 definitions for `T21` in your code, which one is `T12`. (You should always keep an eye on the coloring of code, the `T12` should be blue now, which suggests it's "empty". )

Comment: Thank you so much to point it out ! I have change it.

Comment: I hope to make a plot of w vs Kb or Kb vs w, that is dispersion relation. With different value of w, there may be some imaginary results for Kb, those are gaps. The region plot will gives us the gap and band (real results) in 2-D.

Comment: Then `mu1` is missing.

Comment: Sorry again. my mistake.

Comment: Something like the last one is easy to plot: `Plot[Kb, {w, 0, 10^8}]`, but I don't think we can plot the first two. If the variables in the pictures are consistent with those in your code, then equation for `kx` is missing.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I think i misunderstand some part of the problem. However, plot[Kb,{w,0,10^8}] from you is absolutely working. I was taking very some value for w, which is wrong. Thanks again for your patience with me

Comment: Seems that, for the band-gap diagram, we only need to consider Tr[T], and definition of k should be changed,   k1=kz1=(mu e- kx1^2 )^0.5* w and similar for k2. Then get region plot for Tr[T]>2 on plane of kx vs w.

Comment: And again , thanks for the help

Comment: Now you can post an answer yourself :) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been working on it for a while. The dispersion relation is just as definition Kb-w or w-Kb. So with the definition above for Kb, Bloch wave. In the part we only consider the normal incident wave so `k1=k1z` `k2=k2z` where z is the direction of propagation.

Just use plot for this part.

`Plot[Re[Kb] /. {kx -> 0}, {w, 0, 10^8}, AxesLabel -> {"\[Omega]", "Kb"}, PlotLabel -> "Q3b, Dispersion Relation"]`

[image]

For the band-gap plot, we can no longer use the expression of `k1` and `k2` like this. We need to use the general expression as 
`k1 = (mu1*e1*w^2 - kx^2)^0.5;
k2 = (mu2*e2*w^2 - kx^2)^0.5;` 
so k1 and k2 is on the z-direction (the direction of propagation). So the trace of transfer matrix `Tr(T)` has two parameters. Then with the RegionPlot and condition of `Tr(T)>2` we plot the gaps of the dispersion relation.

`RegionPlot[Re[Tr[T]] > 2, {kx, 0, 10^8}, {w, 0, 10^8}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"kx", "\[Omega]"}, PlotLabel -> "Tr[T]>2"]`

[image]

Both of the plot reflect the relation of Bloch wavenumber and frequency of the wave.
That is all we want.

Comment: In 2nd plot, adding `PlotPoints->50` should improve the result.

Comment: Thanks, I try it, it is really help.